# What is the difference between a linear and angular motor (rigid body physics)?

Tags: physics

As the title asks, what is the difference between a linear motor and an angular motor in rigid body physics?

Answer (score 5):

An angular motor rotates stuff ([angular impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_impulse)), and a linear motor pushes stuff ([linear impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum)):

[image]

[image]