# How can my wheel gear and slider run

Tags: physics

[image]

With the help of physics motor and slider I want to rotate and slide my model.

With the reference image I want to rotate my gear and a red cube I want to slide or move with direction in the image.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "physics motor and slider", there is no such thing in Blender.

Comment: To the left hand panel physics rigid body tools when we click add active and connect we get a bunch of options motor, hinge, point, slider, piston, etc

Comment: Now it's clear. Consider adding this detail to your question description.Other then that. I found excellent tutorials on the topic on Youtube, but writing "blender rigid body slider" and "bleder rigid body motor" and I recommend you to do the same.Cheers

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/51571/599

Comment: This appears to be a re-post of http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/66456/599. Please avoid re-posting questions in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main trick with many rigidbody constraints is getting the constraint's empty aligned the way you want. Though before aligning anything, me must first create something to align:

### Create a constraint

1. If you haven't already, add rigid body physics to your objects via *3D view > Tool Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>) *> Physics*. *Active* objects will move, *Passive* objects won't.
2. Create a constraint between the objects by selecting them and clicking *3D view > Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) *> Physics > Constraints > Connect*. This will create an empty with a rigid body constraint connecting the selected objects (for more advanced applications, this can be used on [more than two objects at once](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7280/599)).
3. In the redo menu, select *Motor* as the constraint type.
4. Select the newly created empty, and rotate it so its local X axis is aligned with the axis you want the motor to rotate around.
5. Enable *Angular Motor* in *Properties > Physics*

[image]

Now our the gear should rotate when we play the simulation:

[image]

Well, it *did* rotate, but it also fell down. To prevent that, we'll have to use a second constraint to actually attach it to the cylinder.

### Use multiple constraints together

Add a second constraint by again following the steps above, but this time pick *Hinge* for the constraint type and rotate the hinge empty so that its local **Z** axis is aligned with the axis of rotation.
<sub>don't ask me why one is X and one is Z..</sub>

Once you get the correct empties oriented the right ways, your gear should now behave like this:

[image]

### Apply the same process for a slider

The process for a motorized slider is very similar, but this time you'll want a *Motor* constraint set to *Linear Motor* instead of *Angular Motor*, and a *Slider* constraint instead of a *Hinge* constraint. This time both constraint empties should have their local X axes aligned with the axis along which the cube should slide.

Once you have this set up, try enabling and adjusting the *Lower* *Upper* limits on the hinge constraint. These control how far the cube is allowed to slide (in blender units).

If you want the cube to slide back and forth (or do anything besides move in one direction at a constant rate), you can drive or animate the *Target Velocity* of the linear motor constraint:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats the perfect answer with the description. Thanks thats what i needed. A question. As soon as we get the axis in the motor which direction i have to rotate so that gear rotate. I have rotate every where but the gear did not rotate. Whats the basic i mean which axis to be on top or which axis pointed the rotation is taken

Comment: @atek For the motor constraint, the empty's local X axis should be pointing through the middle of the gear (i.e. aligned with the desired axis of rotation).